# Generate data using for loop in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

`plan` is a matrix in data.

```
for i = 1:5
  for j = 1:3
    for k = 1:plan(j,i)
      C(i,j,k) = SUB(j,i);
    end
  end
end
```

How to model same in `GAMS`. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Loops are often overused by users unfamiliar with GAMS. In GAMS explicit loops are the exception: usually we want to use implicit loops. Like:

```
c(i,j,k)$(ord(k)<=plan(j,i)) = sub(j,i);
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing is that you have to think about the final output C as a matrix with given dimensions. That is, the size of the third dimension k must be determined before hand. Probably as the maximum of all plan(j,i) values. So I am going to call the maximum value of the index k as capital K. In that case you can do that as follows:

```
SET i /1*5/;
SET j /1*3/;
SET k /1*K/;

Loop (i,
  Loop (j,
    Loop (k,
      If (ord(k) <= plan(j,i), C(i,j,k) = SUB(j,i););
    );
  );
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I use same C(i,j,k) as indices to formulate my constraints?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you add further details?